# Android Trusted Web App: passing objects (not strings) from Java to a TWA

Tags: android, twa

I have been able to successfully create a TWA that calls up a PWA. I am looking at a way in which the Android environment (java) can send an object to a specific function inside the PWA. In my case it is a array-buffer.

The need is similar to what is being done in my Desktop app (via Electron), where the array buffer is passed using the `send-message` and `receive-message` protocol using some sort of inter-process-communication.

I am assuming that once the PWA site is loaded (known to the Android side of things), it can make a send message emitter call that will be picked up by the Javascript receive message event. Something like that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thanks @andreban for the reference. Unfortunately what is mentioned does not help my use-case. It mentions how to send info using query parameters (essentially strings). I would like to send a buffer as I mentioned.

Comment: The last bit of that answer says: "It is not possible to establish a communication bridge between the web app and the Android app at runtime (like a postMessage channel)". In short, what you are looking for is not possible.

Comment: hmm. yes missed that. I am exploring the bridge options based on this link:  https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=4426. If successful I will update this post. Thank @andreban

Comment: @andreban: would it be possible with ReactNative. I am not very familiar with it. In my use case, I wish to read the contents of a file that is tapped from the device and send it to some Javascript code for processing. Thanks

Comment: This should be possible with the Android WebView.

Comment: okay. I was avoiding that line of thinking because of the obvious advantages of TWA ... but may have to settle for it. I will investigate. Thanks for the info @andreban